# Why are numeric character references used in .NET method comments?

Tags: c#, character-encoding

I noticed the comment summary for the `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult()` method uses the numeric character reference `&#39;` for an apostrophe.

```
// Summary:
        //     Creates a System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1 that&#39;s completed successfully with
        //     the specified result.
```

This is the version information in the file:

```
#region Assembly System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
// C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Runtime.dll
#endregion
```

Here is a screeshot:
[image]

I have written comments in C# that use the apostrophe, not encoded.
Why is it encoded in this comment?

Comment: Where are you seeing this? It doesn't exist in the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,11a386e7d7cae64a).

Comment: I also don't see that in the IDE when I view the symbols definition and comment for `FromResult`.

Comment: Its an interesting question, and obviously even if it was the case there is no obvious reason (programming reason) why this is the case, so it comes down to why did someone do this.. and the answer is subjective and most likely not very satisfying, who knows. might have been an accident, might be just your environment, might be some internal reason, might be anything

Comment: It's possible nobody actually typed that and it's an artifact of escaping/processing the XML-based comments. We may never know.

Comment: @Sweeper I've added a screenshot to the question.

Answer (score 2):

It's a mistake, most likely copied from the Type/Member Signature as HTML Encoded in the clipboard...

```
<Member MemberName="FromResult&lt;TResult&gt;">
  <MemberSignature Language="C#" Value="public static System.Threading.Tasks.Task&lt;TResult&gt; FromResult&lt;TResult&gt; (TResult result);" />
```

...

```
<summary>Creates a <see cref="T:System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1" /> that's completed successfully with the specified result.</summary>
```

Ref, ln 2787: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/blob/master/xml/System.Threading.Tasks/Task.xml

Comment: In the comments under my question, there are people who aren't seeing this in their IDE. I also can't see any &#39; when I search in the Task.xml URL you provided.